# SharePoint Hybrid Question

Tags: office-365, hybrid

Currently the business I work for are looking to move into SharePoint Online by using SharePoint Hybrid.

We currently have an On-Premises farm running on SharePoint 2013. We also have Active Directory, ADFS, Web Application Proxy and DirSync up and running.

We have a Web Application, lets call it CorpOnPrem. This Web Application has one site collection, this being the root and then under that we have multiple different subsites.

The question I have, is the business wants to move parts of CorpOnPrem up to SharePoint online, and leave other parts On-premise while still providing a seamless user experience.

Is this something that is possible using the Web Application Proxy? Is there any advice that can be offered to achieve this?

Any help would be great.

Thanks